# Lots of quotes within a string, Euler 22

Tags: string, quotes

So I am working on Euler 22 and I have a little question. So the supplied string is 46K long and it has a lot of quotes within it. It would not make sense for me to go and do slashes before all of the quotes. I would like to just negate all of the quotes between two points. How do I do this? Is there some syntax, like multi-line commenting where in between two things it negates all of them?

Thanks so much,
William Jestes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your programming language. Some (PHP, HTML, XML, Javascript, many others) allow you to put the string in single quotes. If you do this, the double quotes will not end the string. (The same thing works for double quotes: If you put a string in double quotes, single quotes will not end the string).